# Android : .STL 3d model (Render, Edit & Save/Update)

Tags: android, 3d, stl-format

I want to  develop an android application which can load any 3D object ( of file format either .stl,.obj ) and performing operations like rotation,scaling,coloring or positioning and then saving the entire 3D object with all the changes made to it in .stl format. Does anyone know how to do it??

https://github.com/kshoji/STLViewer

With **STLViewer** library I am able to render & perform some operations on it (like Move, Rotate) but is there any possibility to save/update that 3d object with those changes ?

Comment: We would like to display and annotate a user given 3d model file in Android based mobile device. Can you please help us with it. We have found some resources online that are able to display a 3d model, but annotating is not supported in them.